# TypeError with accessing to coo_matrix by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have coo_matrix `X` and indexes `trn_idx` by which I would like to get access of that maxtrix

```
print (type(X  ), X.shape)
print (type(trn_idx), trn_idx.shape)

<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'> (1503424, 2795253)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1202739,)
```

Calling this way:

```
X[trn_idx]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Either this way:

```
 X[trn_idx.astype(int)] #same error
```

How to access by index?

Comment: `X[trn_idx.astype(int)]`?

Comment: @Divakar ops, misspelling

Comment: Give us minimal sample case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Convert to one of the other sparse formats. `X.tocsr()[idx,:]`. Indexing is not implemented for the `coo` format. This should be clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `coo_matrix` class does not support indexing. You'll have to convert it to a different sparse format.

Here's an example with a small `coo_matrix`:

```
In [19]: import numpy as np

In [20]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

In [21]: m = coo_matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0 ,0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 4, 0]])
```

Attempting to index `m` fails:

```
In [22]: m[0,0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1f78c188393f> in <module>()
----> 1 m[0,0]

TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable

In [23]: idx = np.array([2, 3])

In [24]: m[idx]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a52866a6fec6> in <module>()
----> 1 m[idx]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

If you convert `m` to a CSR matrix, you can index it with `idx`:

```
In [25]: m.tocsr()[idx]
Out[25]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

If you are going to do more indexing, it would be better to save the new array in a variable, and use it as needed:

```
In [26]: a = m.tocsr()

In [27]: a[idx]
Out[27]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [28]: a[0,0]
Out[28]: 0
```

Comment: It's curious that `m[idx]` returns the `scalar` error, as opposed to the `not subscriptable` one.  `not subscriptable` is what I expect when `m.__getitem__` is `not found`.  Apparently both are produced by the base python interpreter.  `[][idx]` also produces the `scalar` error.

Comment: Is m.tocsr() better/faster than m.toarray()? @Warren Weckesser

Answer (score -1):

Try reading this.

> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.todense.html

You need to convert to a dense matrix before accessing via an index.
  Try toarray() method on sparse matrix then you can access then by indexing.

Comment: Will calling such function make that matrix to become big in term of size?

Comment: X.todense()[trn_idx] causes me memory errror

Comment: @Poojan, sparse matrices are usually used because the dense matrix is too big to fit in memory.  Calling `todense()` defeats the purpose of using a sparse matrix.

Comment: @Rocketq Yes it will increase size of the matrix as in sparse matrix only non zero values are stored.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes but here i just give reason why accessing value with indexing gives error for sparse matrix.